# Footer page numbering restarting when using continous sections

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, page-numbers

I am using MS Office 365. I have created a Word Form, with page numbering in the footers. Some of the pages have continuous sections in them (to enable a signature line to be in an unprotected section, when protecting the document), and I've noticed that after a page with a continuous section within it, the page number restarts (from 2).  I have Googled this for hours, and am gathering some kind macro will help - but I have no idea how to use macros.  Is anyone able to help please?  I'm about to throw my laptop out the window lol.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will basically have to continue the page numbering across sections.

There is a [video](https://youtu.be/MGQALp4A8lo) in case you'd like a visual explanation.

Basically you need to right-click on the page number, select "Format page numbers" and then "Continue from previous section". If you wanna cover all sections at once, just select all of the text in the document and then through the "Insert" tab again proceed with formatting the page numbers and continuing them.